# PHP variables, Javascript tags within HTML tags?

Tags: javascript, php, html, tags

Is it possible to get a variable denoted by PHP, and then store it in a Javascript script tag, and then use that script tag in an HTML tag?

So for example:

```
<?php
$rand = rand(0,99999);
$height = 80;
$img = "$rand-height.jpgx";
echo "<script>img='$img' height='$height'</script>";
?>
<form action=validate.php method=get>
     <input type='hidden' name='img' value='<script>document.write(img)>'>
     <a href='http://www.opencaptcha.com'>
           <img src='http://www.opencaptcha.com/img/<script>document.write(img)>' height='<script>document.write(height)>' alt='captcha' border='0' />
     </a>
     <br />
     <input type=text name=code value='Enter The Code' size='35' />
     <input type=submit value=Submit><br>
</form>
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my syntax, or if bringing variables with javascript from PHP into HTML tags is even viable.

Comment: are you talking about something like: `var x = <?php echo $sample; ?>;`  Server side languages are executed first.  You will process all that and then the end markup will process and scripts run, accoridng to the web liftcycle

Answer (score 1):

This is way over complicated.

You can access / write your php variables out in html like this:

```
<?php
$height=40;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<img height="<?= $height ?>" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can echo a PHP variable in your JavaScript, if that's what you're asking.